# successive divisibility of a number by 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2

Tags: divisibility

There is a nine digit number . If you delete the digit at its unit place the remaining number would be divisible by nine, if you delete the digit at its tenth place the remaining number would be divisible by eight and the process continues.

all the digits of the number are unique...what is the required number?

Comment: How can a nine digit number have a digit at the tenth place???

Comment: @barakmanos I think he means the ten's digit.

Comment: yep ten's digit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unique solution is $816543279$. But here is not enough place to describe all the possibilities.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, $81653279$ should be divisible by $5$, no?

Comment: 81654327 is divisible by 9, 8165432 is divisible by 8, 816543 is divisible by 7 etc. That's how I understood the problem. I thought it logic that once deleted stays deleted.